# How to update a plot event driven?

Tags: python, events, matplotlib, plot

How can I update a matplotlib plot event driven?

Background:
I wanna program a tool that displays me measured values I receive via a serial port.
These values will be send by a serial connected device when it has measured values and not when the host requests.

Current State:
It seems there is no way to update a plot manually.
When I call the `plot()`-function more than one time the new plots will be added. Similar to MATLAB or Octave, when you use the "hold on"-Option.
This ends after about 10 calls. Then it is freezed. 
When I clear the figures before update, the whole plot disappears.
At least, when the plot is embedded in a window.
Neither `draw()` nor `show()` provide a remedy.

When I use a single plot figure, there is no easy way to update, because after the call of `show()`, the program flow sticks at this line, until the Window is closed. So the update has to be done in a separate thread.

Both problems will be solved, when I use an animation:

```
import sys
from PyQt4.QtGui import QApplication, QMainWindow, QDockWidget, QVBoxLayout,QTabWidget, QWidget
from PyQt4.QtCore import Qt
from matplotlib import pyplot, animation
from matplotlib.backends.backend_qt4agg import FigureCanvasQTAgg
from random import randint

a = QApplication(sys.argv)
w = QMainWindow()
t = QTabWidget(w)
Tab1 = QWidget()
t.addTab(Tab1, '1st Plot')
t.resize(1280, 300)

x = [1, 2, 3]
Fig1 = pyplot.Figure();
Plot =  Fig1.add_subplot(111);
Plot.plot(x)
Plot.grid();

layout = QVBoxLayout();
layout.addWidget(FigureCanvasQTAgg(Fig1));
Tab1.setLayout(layout);

def UpdateFunction(i):
    x.append(randint(0, 10));
    Plot.clear();
    Plot.plot(x);
    Plot.grid();

Anim = animation.FuncAnimation(Fig1, UpdateFunction, interval=500)

w.showMaximized()
sys.exit(a.exec_())
```

But such an animation is time triggered.
Is there any solution to update event triggered?

The event should be a finished UART read in.

Thank you very much.
Fabian

Comment: Update the artists and call `fig.canvas.draw_idle()`

Comment: An all of the built in plotting functions return the artists they add to the draw tree, ex `ln, = ax.plot(range(32)` and the `ln.set_data(new_x, new_y)`.

Comment: Sorry tcaswell, plot() returns a list and not an object with a set_data-method.

Comment: The comma is important and look inside the list

Comment: @tcaswell Do you receive an information when I paste a comment below or do I have to inform you?

Answer (score 2):

@tcaswell

Thank you!

This is my actual code:

```
import sys
from PyQt4.QtGui import QApplication, QMainWindow, QVBoxLayout,QTabWidget, QWidget
from PyQt4.QtCore import SIGNAL
from matplotlib import pyplot
from matplotlib.backends.backend_qt4agg import FigureCanvasQTAgg
from random import randint
import time
from threading import Thread

a = QApplication(sys.argv)
w = QMainWindow()
t = QTabWidget(w)
Tab1 = QWidget()
t.addTab(Tab1, '1st Plot')
t.resize(1280, 300)

x = [];
x.append(randint(0, 10));
x.append(randint(0, 10));
x.append(randint(0, 10));
Fig1 = pyplot.Figure();
Plot =  Fig1.add_subplot(111);
Line, = Plot.plot(x)
Plot.grid();

layout = QVBoxLayout();
layout.addWidget(FigureCanvasQTAgg(Fig1));
Tab1.setLayout(layout);

def triggerUpdate():
    while True:
        a.emit(SIGNAL('updatePlot()'));
        time.sleep(2);
        print('update triggered!\n')

def updateFunction():
    x.append(randint(0, 10));
    #Plot.clear();
    Line.set_data(range(len(x)), x);
    Fig1.canvas.draw_idle();
    print('update done!\n')

a.connect(a, SIGNAL('updatePlot()'), updateFunction)

t = Thread(target=triggerUpdate);
t.start();
w.showMaximized()

sys.exit(a.exec_())
```

It seems to run, but the content of the plot gets not updated.
The Plot has no canvas. (Although it should have one, otherwise I don't now on what it is plotting when I command it.)

To be honest, I did not understand already the concept of the GUI and plot foo. The missing canvas is covered by its parenting figure. I really don't got it. When there is a figure, what can handle more than one plots, should't each plot have its own canvas?

But I think, here is the problem.

Thank you very much.